# PHP FFMpeg error ffprobe failed to execute command "ffprobe.exe" "-help" "-loglevel" "quiet"

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, compression

I'm searching for a way to compress and convert uploaded videos on my site, I'm trying to use [FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) with this PHP basic code (on windows):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("vendor/autoload.php");
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/FFmpeg/ffmpeg.exe',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/FFmpeg/ffprobe.exe',
    'timeout'          => 3600, // The timeout for the underlying process
    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // The number of threads that FFMpeg should use
));
$video = $ffmpeg->open('input.mp4');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('frame.jpg');
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');
?>
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutionFailureException: ffprobe failed to execute command "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/FFmpeg/ffprobe.exe" "-help" "-loglevel" "quiet" in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\alchemy\binary-driver\src\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner.php:100 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\alchemy\binary-driver\src\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner.php(72): Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->doExecutionFailure('"C:/inetpub/www...') #1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\alchemy\binary-driver\src\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary.php(209): Alchemy\BinaryDriver\ProcessRunner->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), Object(SplObjectStorage), false) #2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\alchemy\binary-driver\src\Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary.php(137): Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), false, NULL) #3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\FFProbe\OptionsTester.php(61): Alchemy\Binary in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\vendor\php-ffmpeg\php-ffmpeg\src\FFMpeg\FFProbe\OptionsTester.php on line 63
```

what am I doing wrong? there are better libraries?

Comment: It's a wild guess but can you try initializing (binary paths) with backward slashes?

Comment: tried but nothing changed

Comment: Did you get it workking @Michele?